# Python code reserves immense amounts of memory

Tags: python, memory

I ran the following code on leetcode and it showed me 14MB of mem conquered for some unknown reason (for me). I know it is lousy since I'm in 10th percentile of noobs, so does anyone could tell me who ate it?

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> int:
        all_freq = {} 
        
        for i in s: 
            if i in all_freq: 
                all_freq[i] += 1
            else: 
                all_freq[i] = 1
        
        number = 0
        flag = False
        
        for i in all_freq:
            number = number + all_freq[i] // 2 
            if all_freq[i] % 2 == 1:
                flag = True
        
        number = number*2
        if flag : number = number +1
            
        return number
```

problem being:
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindrome/

Comment: If this code is called with a very, _very_ large string as the argument, then I can imagine it would take up a lot of memory.

Comment: @JohnGordon Nah, they're just showing the memory of the whole Python process or so, it's never below ~13 MB or so, no matter what a solution does.

Answer (score -1):

The memory consumption depends on the amount of data, instances and test cases, and benchmark of that is not so accurate, just don't worry about it. This'd also pass:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        odds = sum(val & 1 for val in Counter(s).values())
        return len(s) - odds + bool(odds)
```